# SSIS Conditional Split NULL

Tags: ssis, null, split, conditional-statements

I need to detect whether either of two values are null, and if not, whether they differ.

The condition I have in my split is

```
(ISNULL(ModuleLevelId) && !ISNULL(LEV_CODE)) || 
(!ISNULL(ModuleLevelId) && ISNULL(LEV_CODE)) || (ISNULL(LEV_CODE) ? 0 - ModuleLevelId : (DT_I4)LEV_CODE) != ModuleLevelId
```

but I am told that my expression leads to null, i.e. a non-Boolean condition.

Can anyone help me write the condition that will work please?

Many thanks

Patrick

Comment: I have split this conditional and made the first test a null check for either column.  
  
A subsequent condition then performs the cast and the comparison and I still get the message 'Source: Module Check for changes [3192]
   Description: The expression "ModuleLevelId != (DT_I4)LEV_CODE" on "output "LevelId changed" (5356)" evaluated to NULL, but the "component "Check for changes" (3192)" requires a Boolean results.

Comment: OK what you try to do if both values are not null ?  `LEV_CODE - ModuleLevelId` ?  
And what you need to return if one of the values is null ?

Comment: Hi @justin, and thanks for replying. Essentially I'm trying to detect whether there's been a change between two values and this will determine a number of subsequent updates. The problem is NULLs keep breaking the comparisons

Comment: Sorry but your condition is not correct:) after `?` (Then) you can do subtraction but after `:` you **can't** compare values. Brackets closed too incorrectly.

Comment: Hello again @Justin  

Thanks for your persevering with me but I think my Boolean if test is correct. Can you explain which part is wrong?  

(ISNULL(LEV_CODE) ? 0 - ModuleLevelId : (DT_I4)LEV_CODE) should evaluate correctly and give me either "0 - ModuleLevelId" or "LEV_CODE casted to an INT", both of which should compare without issue to "ModuleLevelId"  

Which part of this is incorrect?

Comment: This corected `(ISNULL(ModuleLevelId) && !ISNULL(LEV_CODE)) || (!ISNULL(ModuleLevelId) && ISNULL(LEV_CODE)) || (ISNULL(LEV_CODE) ? 0 - ModuleLevelId : (DT_I4)(LEV_CODE)) != ModuleLevelId` condition gives me results `30 20 TRUE`, `NULL 40 TRUE`, `50 NULL TRUE`, `30 30 False` (LEV_CODE, ModuleLevelId, Derived column boolean data type ). So condition works this what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(ISNULL(ModuleLevelId) && !ISNULL(LEV_CODE)) || 
(!ISNULL(ModuleLevelId) && ISNULL(LEV_CODE)) ||
((ISNULL(LEV_CODE) ? 0 - ModuleLevelId :(DT_I4)LEV_CODE) != ModuleLevelId)
```

I think you need to surround your third term:

```
 (ISNULL(LEV_CODE) ? 0 - ModuleLevelId :(DT_I4)LEV_CODE) != ModuleLevelId
```

with ().  I think the expression engine is parsing it incorrectly as

```
((ISNULL(ModuleLevelId) && !ISNULL(LEV_CODE)) || 
(!ISNULL(ModuleLevelId) && ISNULL(LEV_CODE)) ||
(ISNULL(LEV_CODE) ? 0 - ModuleLevelId :(DT_I4)LEV_CODE)) != ModuleLevelId
```

or (Boolean || Boolean || INT) != INT

when what you want is 
(Boolean || Boolean || Boolean)

Try the topmost code in this answer.

Comment: Hi @William.

Many thanks for this, it has worked perfectly.

Patrick